# why is my icon not to the right side

Tags: html, css, icons

I have an icon which should be floating right. But there is always a lot of space between the right side and the icon. I do not why this is the case. But it should be 5px left from the right side. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I use the google icons like you can see in my code. How can I get the icon completely to the right?

```css
/* Initial body */
body {
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}


/* Basic styling */

.header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-top: 0px;  
}

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.counter {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.material-icons.md-36 {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.icons-right {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    align-text: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lan="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="A page about me">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web developer, projects">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>title</title>

    <!-- google icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- the icon font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="body">
        <div class="header">

            <div class="icon-menu">
                    <a href="/logout"><i class="material-icons md-36 icons-right">lock outline</i></a>

                <span class="icons-right">person</span>
                <div class="click"><i class="material-icons md-36">menu</i></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't understood the question completely. What I found out was there is <padding-right : 5px> and <margin-right: 5px> associated with element <i>. If you disable one of them then you might get the desired behavior.

Comment: no, it will still be a lot to far.

Comment: I will delete that css to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes. Just add a width to the lock icon.

```css
body {
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}


/* Basic styling */

.header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-top: 0px;  
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.counter {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.material-icons.md-36 {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.icons-right {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    align-text: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.lock-icon{
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lan="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="A page about me">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web developer, projects">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>title</title>

    <!-- google icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- the icon font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="body">
        <div class="header">

            <div class="icon-menu">
                    <a href="/logout"><i class="material-icons md-36 icons-right lock-icon">lock outline</i></a>

                <span class="icons-right">person</span>
                <div class="click"><i class="material-icons md-36">menu</i></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is on the right, the container is anyway - but it is as wide as the available space...hard to tell since its transparent.

If you give the class="material-icons md-36 icons-right" a width (say 20px) it'll make the icon only fill that width and be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple way to do it:

```
button {
    padding: 1em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    padding: 3em;
    width: 400px;
}
button img {
    height: 4em;
    width: auto;
    margin: -1.25em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
button p {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

The reason why I've used a button here is because by default it centers its contents, though any form of horizontal centering (that also works on `block`s).

Tweak the `margin` and `margin-left` of the `img` and the `font-size` of the `p` until you're comfortable with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by giving the .material-icons.md-36 a negative margin-right

```
.material-icons.md-36 {
    font-size: 36px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: -250px;
    color: white;
}
```

Now it´s on the right side.